# How to make a request reach all instances behind a load balancer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, load-balancing, spring-cloud

I need to make sure a specific notification request reaches all instances behind a load balancer, I am using java, Spring Cloud, AWS, How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a message queue service.

Comment: Please elaborate more, do you mean like for example kafka? I can send 1 specific request to it, and it will distribute it to all the instances I need?

Comment: Or any AMQP broker… you send the request and it's distributed to who is listening to…

Comment: But Kafka can do the job too right? I have not done something like this before but sounds great, and would prefer using Kafka I have heard it is one of the best, also RabbitMQ seems to be good?

Comment: Yes Kafka is another concept covering this use case.

Comment: Hey mate, one question, I was discussing this approach with my coworkers, but some of they said that it does not solve our case because, suppose we have 5 instances, only 1 of the will "acknowledge" the message from Kafka, not the 5 instances, so my question is if this message that is consumed, is going to be consumed by the 5 instances or only 1?

Comment: my first idea was AMQP... read the doc, here https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html some clear examples of the different patterns... publish/subscribe may be what you need.

Comment: I just gave it a look, I think it suits the case yes, one last question mate, this will work with autoscaling instances? I did not mention that but I guess it will hehe

Comment: When we had to do that some years ago, the image of the instances contained a "registration process" that was sending the IP of the instance to the AMQP broadcaster, then the "news" was broadcasted and the listeners of that "kind of news" get the notice and did their job... among them one was in charge to update the load balancer settings... We used the init mechanism of Linux to make sure the network was up before trying to broadcast. And of course symmetrically at instance shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Use a message queue or topic-based communication system to publish messages that need to be received by all instances. Systems like RabbitMQ, Apache Kafka, ActiveMQ.